# Transform a string into ISO datetime format | Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

So I get the date and time which is, for example, 17.11.2021 and 12:44. Now I want to convert this date and time into the formate which Freemarker is using (yyyy-MM-dd hh:dd:mm:ss). However the problem here is that I can't convert it properly. I tried like:

```
${myDateTime?datetime.iso?string("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}
```

But this wont work. I always get an error message. Can anyone explain or show me the correct formation in this case ?

Comment: Is `myDateTime` in ISO format? Because `?datetime.iso` assumes that. What's the error message?

Comment: Yeah this is part of the problem. `myDateTime` is like 17.11.2021 12:44. The error message that I get is:                                                                                     `Script error: (Root Causes: _TemplateModelException: The string doesn't match the expected date/time/date-time format. The string to parse was: "Nov 17, 2021 12:44:00 PM". The expected format was: "I(...)...SO 8601 (subset) date-time"`        Pls ignore the datetime format in the error message.

Comment: Like the thing here is, that I have to convert `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm` to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` in order to covert it to the ISO datetime format. But I dont know how tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `myDateTime` is a `String` (and not already a `Date` object), and it looks like `17.11.2021 12:44`, you can convert it to ISO format like this:

```
${myDateTime?datetime("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")?string.iso}
```

Above `myDateTime?datetime("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")` converts the string to a `Date` (which is a format-independent representation), and then `?string.iso` formats the `Date` with ISO format.

Note that it would be much cleaner if `myDateTime` was a `Date`, not a `String`. Then you just do this: `${myDateTime?string.iso}`

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly fine. This was the answere I was looking for.